# Are derivatives of analytic functions also analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

My lecturer says at one result of Cauchy's integral formula is that if $f(z)$ is analytic at $z=z_0$, then $f^{(n)}(z)$ is too analytic at $z=z_0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
However, how do we show that the definitie integral $f^{(n)}(z_0) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \oint_C \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz$ always exists/is solvable?

Comment: we just prove it for the first derivative: the derivative is analytic, also its Taylor series is the derivative of the Taylor series of the original and radius of convergence is the same. Your $n$ result is by induction

Comment: To answer this, we need to know what you've covered. Cauchy's theorem, power series ....?